# Creating dataframe column with text strings from dummy columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I've used get_dummies to create several columns (df.earth, df.wind, df.water, df.fire, df.heart - for example) and groupby to aggregate rows, so now a row can have multiple dummy columns with 1. The dataframe now looks like this:

ID   Earth   Wind   Water   Fire   Heart
12   0             1             1              0          1
13   1             0             0              0           0
14   1             0             1              0           0

I need to create a column that checks each dummy column and writes the column names that apply for each row that would look like this:

ID   Earth   Wind   Water   Fire   Heart  Powers
12   0              1             1               0              1              Wind, Water, Heart
13   1               0              1              0            0             Earth, Water
14   1              0            1               0            0           Earth, Water, Heart

I'm not really sure where to start, and my searching hasn't gotten me very far.

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Comment: You can start by showing us some of the data.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I added some sample data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
df['Powers'] = df.apply(lambda s: ', '.join(s.index[s.eq(1)]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
            { 'A': [0, 0, 0],
            'B': [1, 0, 0],
            'C': [0, 1, 0],
            'D': [0, 0, 0],
            'E': [1, 0, 1],
            'F': [0, 0, 1],
            }
                )

df

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   0   1   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

Your probably looking at a df like the one above. You can do the following to pull the columns that contain 1.

```
columns = []
for col in df.T:
    columns.append(df.T[df.T[col] == 1].index.tolist())

has1 = pd.DataFrame(columns).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)
df['Is1'] = has1

df

    A   B   C   D   E   F   Is1
0   0   1   0   0   1   0   B, E
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   C
2   0   0   0   0   1   1   E, F
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to only check certain columns? So if I wanted it to skip the first four columns and only write in E/F?

Comment: Change ```columns.append(df.T[df.T[col] == 1].index.tolist())
``` line to ```columns.append(df[['E','F']].T[df[['E','F']].T[col] == 1].index.tolist())```

Comment: You can also change RafaelC  code to ```df['Powers'] = df[['E','F']].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(s.index[s.eq(1)]), axis=1)```